# Objective C/Xcode- Format data input by user into UIAlertView as Currency

Tags: xcode, delegates, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a working implementation of a delegate method for a UITextField (below). I have a UIAlertView that pops up in my interface, and it is styled with the UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPassWordInput, with the second text field's secure text entry property set to NO (effectively giving me a UIAlertView with two text fields). The UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad becomes first responder for each text field.

I would like to adjust these textfields to work with the delegate method posted below, to format all input into these text fields as currency. I understand that I can manually call the delegate method and pass the text field in as the first parameter, but I am not sure what to pass in as the Range and Replacement String parameters.

Here is the UITextField delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    double number = [text intValue] * 0.01;
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.2lf", @"$",number];
    return NO;
}
```

Thank you

Best...SL

Comment: You should take a look at NSNumberFormatter, which can format and parse numeric strings representing currency. Plus, it works for currency symbols other than $.

Comment: Can it format the input in real time?

Comment: yes but allocating the formatter instance is relatively expensive and should be done beforehand, eg in your view controller's viewWillAppear method.